# RobotFrameWork: How can I gettext from a page and input text in another?

Tags: robotframework

Open Browser bla bla website

```
${gettext2}   Get Text  xpath=//tr[2]/td[1]
```

Open browser bla bla website2

```
Input Text    num    ${gettext2}
```

that doesn't work... so how do I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to set a variable in one test case, and use it in another?

Comment: please provide all your code snippet. Maybe you got some syntax issue

Comment: In addition to your code, please also share your observations including errors. Right now everyone is guessing what your issue is and that is far from constructive use of their time.

Comment: okay I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet should work assuming the element exists and has text in it:

```
${text_element}=    xpath://tr[2]/td[1]
${input_element}=    xpath://input

Open Browser   https://www.google.com   browser=ff    alias=browser_1
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${text_element}
${gettext2}    Get Text    ${text_element}

Open Browser   https://www.bing.com    browser=ff    alias=browser_2
Switch Browser    browser_2
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${input_element}
Input Text     ${input_element}    ${gettext2}
```

Comment: There is no harm with the equal sign. It should works too. I've done it with no issue. However, your answer should help tijnn. I think maybe he got other syntax issue. It would be good if @tijnn provide all the robot scripts that he has written.

Comment: @Temizzi Ye you're right. In the [docs](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Explicit%20locator%20strategy) it has both

Comment: The equal sign was the old way of separating the strategy from the value, now deprecated in favor of colon; it is still working and supported though.

Comment: So what is it exactly that makes this work instead of the code I preleminary gave?

Comment: for my feeling
The  Wait Until Page Contains Element   made the difference.  (it inputted the text to the element at the moment the element was'nt there yet or something).

Comment: @tijnn it could have been that, or the `Switch Browser` - not sure which one is active for SeleniumLibrary upon creating a new one with `Open Browser` (I'm also guessing here btw).

Comment: @tijnn, if you think this answer is helpful, then you must give credit to the person who had answered it :) Just click accept answer.

Comment: @tijnn It's hard to tell exactly what fixed the issue when we don't have a full view of what symptoms/error you were getting. It could've been that you were trying to click the element before it had rendered on the page, it could have been that you did not switch browsers correctly, it could be something else entirely. We are all just speculating in the comments without the full story.